# Hovering on animated navbar goes wrong

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem.

I have an animated navigation bar on my html website, so that if you scroll it'll change. But I want that if I'm hovering on the changed navbar, it'll change back to his normal state. But that doesn't work at all. I hope you guys can help me.

Code here:

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
                var header = document.querySelector(".navbar");
                header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
            });
            let navbar = document.querySelector(".sticky");
            navbar.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ){
                navbar.classList.toggle("navbar", navbar.onmouseover);}
            , false);
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.head {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url('pictures/head.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}
.head h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 100px 100px 25px;
    font-family: Copperplate, Monaco, "Lucida Console", monospace;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.head h2 {
    
    font-family: Copperplate, Monaco, "Lucida Console", monospace;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
}
.navbar .dropbtn {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px 16px 14px 16px;
    
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
    color: black;
    transition: 0.6s;
    
}
.sticky .dropbtn {
    background: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px 16px 14px 16px;
    
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
    color: white;
    transition: 0.6s;
    
}


.navbar {
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: visible;
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    transition: 0.6s;
.navbar .dropdownlinks {
    float: left;
}
    
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: -2px;
    
    
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 160px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px black;
    
    
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

.navbar img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
    padding-right: 4px;
    top: 0;
    float: left;
    
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}

.sticky {
    background: none;
    transition: 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<header>    
            <div class="navbar">


                <img src="pictures/gear_icon.png" alt="icon">
                <div class="dropdownlinks">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropbtn">F1 history</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="#">All the teams</a>
                            <a href="#">All world champions</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropbtn">News and times</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="#">Driver and team news</a>
                            <a href="#">Liveblog</a>
                            <a href="#">Calender</a>
                            <a href="#">Archives</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropbtn">This season</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="#">Driver's standings</a>
                            <a href="#">Constructor's standings</a>
                            <a href="#">All current drivers</a>
                            <a href="#">All current teams</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
```

It's a formula 1 website btw, so if you love formula 1 please help me:)

Comment: Why are you doing `navbar.classList.toggle("navbar", navbar.onmouseover);`? `onmouseover` will probably always be undefined since nothing was assigned to it, which means you class will never be added. You need to `classList.add` when the `mouseover` event fires, and then `classList.remove` when the `mouseleave` event fires. Although this is probably better solved in CSS with the `:hover` state.

Comment: Thanks, now I think about it, it isn't hard to do it with the :hover state. I did it and it worked. Mucha gracías!